# Symfony 4 on Azure Windows - Very slow output (3-10 secounds)

Tags: php, symfony, azure, azure-virtual-machine

I'm developing on Azure PHP applications with Symfony 4.
Currently is a standard installation without a database or extensions:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/setup.html

I start the server with "php bin / console server: run"
Then I call "https://localhost:8000" in the browser.

The page "Hello Word" appears after ~ 5-10 seconds,
although the page is rendered within ~ 300ms
(internal Degug Tool of Symfony, when Symfony dont
have to rebuild the cache ...).

Something slows down the every output, after the page
is rendered with PHP ...The same program runs on my
laptop at lightning speed, after 300ms the page is visible ...)

I would be very happy about any help.
I use Azure Virtual Machine (Windows Server 2012)

Many thanks & Best regards
Simon

Comment: i dont know the reason why but i know that some filesystem commands like file_exist() are slower under windows than on linux, Therefor i switched over from windows to Ubuntu for my Symfony  development projects which gave me huge speedprofits,

Comment: Thanks for reply. But when I install the same Symfony 4 project on my home laptop (old one, Windows 7)
it is extremly fast. Within ~300ms (symfony render time). So I think it is not a general windows problem,
its a special Azure Virtual Machine problem ... ;(

Comment: Does symfony generate cache files?

Comment: yes, Symfony generates a lot of cache files. but normally you can see this in the in the debug toolbar. This goes fast < 300ms ...